# Как убрать вертикальную полосу прокрутки в GridView,ListView

Tags: java, android

Как убрать вертикальную полосу прокрутки в GridView,ListView? И ещё как сделать в эти View АБСОЛЮТНО по всему экрану,а то при скроллинге видны сверху и снизу небольшие полосы?

Answer (score 2):

Укажите свойство GridView или ListView в XML

```
android:scrollbars="none"
```